# How do I fix this django error:'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, django, authentication

There were a couple of other similar questions with answer but none of them fixed my problem. I am getting 'You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user' every time I try to create a new user using by sign up in Django. Here is my view:

```
def signupUser(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            form.save()
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

I had added `user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` in hopes of fixing the problem, but it did nothing.

My forms.py:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    password1=forms.CharField(help_text='Your password cant be too similar to your other personal information. Your password must contain at least 8 characters. Your password cant be a commonly used password. Your password cant be entirely numeric.', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

By the way, in my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS are     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' and 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

Comment: Put that in the `settings.py`, not in your view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Multiple Authentication Backend for one project, HOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064443/django-multiple-authentication-backend-for-one-project-how)

Comment: Erip, I have already defined multiple backends in my settings file.

Comment: Add full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your view function. I don't know how this worked out for you, but for the sake of clarity, I'd like to point out some of it.

Primarily, I am re-writing your view to a more suitable way,

```
def signupUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Here, the view is meant to be for creating new users. So, you may need to call `form.save()` method before calling `authenticate()` function. Before committing to the database you are trying to authenticate the user which is not created yet. Check if your view does actually logs in any user. Then, `authenticate()` function returns None, if there is any mismatch in the credentials, so, check that too. Or else, Django would raise an `AttributeError`, when calling `login()` function.

I seriously doubt that your view logs in any user, because you are redirecting to same page regardless of the success of logging in. Its quite counter-intuitive, makes it harder to debug. Simply redirect to the home page when login is successful and to the login page if its not.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that a user was still being created even though this error was showing up, so I guess it gets the job done. But to get rid of this error, I changed my view to this:

```
def signupUser(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            form.save()

            try:
                login(request, user)
            except ValueError:
                return redirect('home')

            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

This strangely(at least strangely to me) worked out. A user was created and it can be properly logged into. I don't think this has any bad side effects, but I will wait to mark my solution correct just in case that there is a better solution.